# ¿Como activar el zoom en la librería LEAFLET cuando se aprieta la tecla Ctrl?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Como puedo hacer para que en el mapa no se pueda hacer zoom si la tecla de ctrl no esta presionada, busco un efecto como en el de google maps, que si no se tiene la tecla ctrl no funciona el zoom.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que necesitas usar el gestureHandling: 'greedy' en las opciones de tu mapa, puedes echar un vistazo a la documentación: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/interaction#gestureHandling

te anexo un pequeño ejemplo de cómo se haría.

```
 const map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, {
  center: { 0, 0 },
  zoom: 4,
  gestureHandling: 'greedy'
});
```

Comment: bueno no es google maps, y no me funciono, quiero controlar el zoom con la tecla ctrl y el mouse, pero no se como, la libreria de leaflet al parecer no trae esa opcion

Comment: Creo que ya te entendí, para ello podrías crear un L map, por medio de la funcion click o focus, puedes manipular de igual forma los objetos dom ya que al final es JS te dejo un pequeño ejemplo. map.on('click', function() {
  if (map.scrollWheelZoom.enabled()) {
    map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();
    }
    else {
    map.scrollWheelZoom.enable();
    }
  });

Comment: map.on('click', function() {
  if (map.scrollWheelZoom.enabled()) {
    map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();
    }
    else {
    map.scrollWheelZoom.enable();
    }
  });

Comment: map.once('focus', function() { map.scrollWheelZoom.enable(); });

Comment: igual puedes hecharle un vistazo a ésta libreria, que puedes embeber con la de leaflet : https://github.com/ccampbell/mousetrap

Comment: ok, le intentare, gracias por la informacion